# Limiting post list by taxonomy

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, wp-query

I currently have the following code pulling the 10 latest posts from a specific category, I would like to filter those posts to a certain custom taxonomy which I've set up called article type.

What do I need to modify to incorporate this filter?

```
<div id="btcc" class="main-headline-box">          
<h2>Features</h2>        
<?php $btcc_query = new WP_Query('category_name=btcc&showposts=10'); ?><ul>
<?php while ($btcc_query->have_posts()) : $btcc_query->the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Permanent Link to: 
<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?><li class="read-more"><a href="">Read more from the BTCC Archive</a></li></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [search in codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) shows how to do that :

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'people',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'bob'
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**EDIT:** do not use `showposts`, it's deprecated.

Comment: Perfect, thanks worked it out in the end using this solution also updated so query wasn't using `showposts`